# Nginx rewrite not working (Kirby CMS Cachebuster)

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, kirby

Nginx shall rewrite `/assets/css/main.1448958665.css` to `/assets/css/main.css`. But trying to get that file, it returns a `404`.

This is my Nginx config for the site:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    server_name example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    rewrite ^/(content|site|kirby)$ /error last;
    rewrite ^/content/(.*).(txt|md|mdown)$ /error last;
    rewrite ^/(site|kirby)/(.*)$ /error last;

    location /assets {
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/(.+)\.(\d+)\.(js|css)$ /$1.$3 break;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    location /panel {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /panel/index.php?$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ (?:^|/)\. {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ (?:\.(?:bak|config|sql|fla|psd|ini|log|sh|inc|swp|dist)|~)$ {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~* \.(svg|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$ {
        expires 1y;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

I am using Kirby CMS with the Cachebuster plugin if that does help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem relates to [how nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html). Your `location ~* \.(svg|js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$` takes precedence over `location /assets`.

A simple fix (assuming that it contains no php) would be to move its precedence above regex by writing it as:

```
location ^~ /assets { ... }
```

In which case you may want to add an `expires` directive to the container also.

Comment: Great, thanks! Thought the order is important, not the way of defining the rules. Working now!  :)